# Application.Exit event not called on Logoff or Shutdown

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"          
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="ActiveWords.App" 
         Startup="Application_Startup" 
         Exit="Application_Exit" 
         SessionEnding="Application_SessionEnding"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
```

SessionEnding is correctly called when user is either logging off or computer is shutting down.

However Application_Exit is ONLY getting called when the app is shutting down normally.

According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the event should also fire when "The user ends the session by logging off or shutting down."

What am I missing?

Comment: Because the `Exit` is not being fired for session ending, the only thing in the `SessionEnding` handler is a call to Shutdown, however I have now removed the `SessionEnding` handler and still `Exit` is not being called

Comment: Your assertion that the `Exit` event is not being raised is insufficient. Please provide a good [mcve] and explain how you've determined that the event is not being raised. What _specifically_ are you observing that leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: I have numerous log statements in my `Exit` event - when the user logsoff or shuts down their computer event nothing appears in the log file. However if a uses the `SystemEvents.SessionEnded` event that that event is raised as expected. For now this is a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ShutdownMode property to OnExplicitShutdown, it requires an explicit Shutdown method call to stop the application. Otherwise, the application continues running in the background.
[ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)